# MarkLogic 8 - After upgrade we are getting 405 Method Not Allowed on a GET

Tags: xquery, upgrade, http-get, marklogic

This started happening after we upgraded MarkLogic from 7 to 8.
We had various rest endpoints that worked fine.

Then after the upgrade we started intermittently getting this on various GET requests:

```
<error-response xmlns='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error'>
  <status-code>405</status-code>
  <status>Method Not Allowed</status>
  <message>405 Method Not Allowed</message>
</error-response>
```

How do I resolve this?

> Note: We had this same issue on some of our POST requests, but we were able to fix that by marking the post methods with: **%rapi:transaction-mode("update")**

Comment: Did you see the release notes on Rest API incompatibilities? https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_52451

Comment: I will try to add:
%rapi:transaction-mode("update")

To the get function.
That's the only thing that looks suspect.

Comment: Are these resource service extensions?  What are the URI and headers for the requests (including the mime type)?

Comment: I seem to be getting 405's on GETs and POSTs and it seems random...sometimes the response returns data sometimes I get 405. Adding the rapi:transaction-mode("update") did not fix it.

Comment: Did you manage to create a complete, independent repro?